# Media Query targeting Specific Image

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here... I have two images in "sliderbox" and I need one of them to disappear on mobile and smaller devices.  I'm trying to create a new class and then hiding that class, but nothing is happening.  Thanks in advance!

Source:

```
<section class="sliderbox" id="menu-homepage">
    <img src="img/arrow.png" class="arrow" alt="image" width="300" height="85"    align="right">
```

Media Query:

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .theme-default .nivo-caption{
    font-size: 21px;
    }

    .theme-default .nivoSlider{
    height: inherit;
    }
.sliderbox-class-arrow {
    display: none;
}
```

Live @ gradepowerbrandon.com/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are doing it incorrectly.

This is how it should be:

```
.sliderbox img.arrow {
    display: none;
```

You must not write the word 'class'. Just the name.

Comment: Thanks @siyah!  I knew I had to be doing something wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your test page. It comes to me that you probably just forgot to add '.sliderbox-class-arrow' class to your image? I tried to add it, and it works fine for me.